# Error C1010 при компиляции программы в Visual C++

Tags: windows, c++, visual-c++

У меня Microsoft Visual C++ 2010. Мне дали код и сказали и скопировать и запустить. Делаю я так: захожу в программу -> создать проект -> Консольное приложение Win32 (как мне объясняли). Копирую код и нажимаю <kbd>F7</kbd> и вот что пишет:

> `1>------ Построение начато: проект: 234, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  stdafx.cpp
>   1>  234.cpp
>   1>c:\users\саша\desktop\234\234\234.cpp(1): warning C4627: #include <math.h>: пропущен при поиске использования предкомпилированного заголовка
>   1>          Добавление директивы в "StdAfx.h" или перестройка предкомпилированного заголовка
>   1>c:\users\саша\desktop\234\234\234.cpp(33): fatal error C1010: непредвиденный конец файла во время поиска предкомпилированного заголовка. Возможно, вы забыли добавить директиву "#include "StdAfx.h"" в источник.
>   Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0`

**Сам код:**

```
#include <math.h>

const float LEFT = 0, RIGHT = 4, TABUL = 0.1;
float fun1(float farg)
{
    float ftemp = 0;
    int ni;
    for (ni = 1; ni <= 5; ni = ni + 1)
        ftemp = ftemp + sqrt((farg + ni) / ni);
    return ftemp;
}

float fun2(float farg)
{
    float ftemp = log(2 * farg * farg) + 3 * sin(farg);
    return ftemp;
}

void main()
{
    float fx = LEFT;
    float fy;
    while (fx <= RIGHT) {
        if (fx <= 2)
            fy = fun1(fx);
        else
            fy = fun2(fx);
        fx = fx + TABUL;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eizembruk, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Создайте `Empty C++ Project` и добавьте туда файл `main.cpp` с указанным вами содержимым.

Comment: @Deleted, "кнопка 101010 редактора" - это что за кнопка?? Что-то не припомню таких кнопок в VS.

Comment: @freim, редактор это должность, а 101010 его номер телефона

Answer (score 2):

**1> stdafx.cpp** уже по это строчке ясно что неправильно создал проект!

надо:

файл-> создать проект-> Консольное приложение Win32

далее выскочит вот такая картинка

http://s59.radikal.ru/i165/1209/b1/b1ba1cc58e75.jpg

далее

http://s003.radikal.ru/i203/1209/06/ac4c4c414aeb.jpg

далее

http://i068.radikal.ru/1209/ea/ac4087d7b8f5.jpg

в конце получаем запущенную и нормально отработавшею программу...

http://i037.radikal.ru/1209/d9/550b21c56933.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще попробовать в настройках проекта отключить precompiled headers