# Visual Studio не дает объявить массив int mas[n], где n - переменная вводимая пользователем

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Перешел на `Visual Studio`, вручную создал проект для чистого C++, не дает объявить массив `int mas[n]`, где `n` - переменная вводимая пользователем.
Раньше кодил на `g++`, `Visual Studio` выдает "требуется константное выражение" и еще пучок ошибок связанных с этим массивом. 
P.S. Есть ли в `Visual Studio` пресет для чистого C++, без `stdafx.h`? И что это вообще за `stdafx.h`?

Comment: сделайте просто замену

    int a[n];

на 

   std::vector<int> a(n);

весь остальной код скорее всего будет работать, если только не используются хитро указатели.

Answer (score 2):

1. вы неправильно создали проект для консольного С++, вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/143258/windows-visual-c-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=144597#144597) в своём ответе я расписал порядок создания для студии 2012
2. во вторых, то что вы описали не должно работать даже в g++ так как **`n`** не константа и компилятор на стадии компиляции не знает сколько выделить памяти под массив в стеке.

p.s. если вам нужен массив и его изначальный размер не известен то используйте динамическую память через **new\delete**, или воспользуйтесь контейнером из STL (например вектором)

Comment: g++ умеет так работать с массивами.

Comment: @KoVadim: да, но это — нестандартное расширение языка. http://pastebin.com/m9d4cbrW

Comment: @VladD   @KoVadim  

под рукой нет g++,  вот такое он откомпилирует? (это то что у автора, `"где n - переменная вводимая пользователем"` )

    int main()
    {
        int n = -1;
        cin>>n;
        char array[n];
        return 0;
    }


по идеи не должно... (ведь на стадии компиляции неизвестна **`n`**)

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat: это расширение GNU, на ideone откомпилировалось: http://ideone.com/Fn48T6. g++ транслирует это в вызов `alloca`, функцию выделения на стеке (про `alloca`: [[1]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html), [[2]](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Advantages-of-Alloca.html), [[3]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice), [[4]](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/2419260.flat)).

Comment: @ProkletyPirat, в общем, переходите на GNU (видите, какие полезные гнусные штучки...)

Comment: @avp за нестандартные фокусы надо наказывать.

Comment: @alexlz, а нужно? 

Просто когда достаточно много людей начинает использовать какую-то новую удобную штучку, то она становится стандартом.

К тому же, компиляторы GNU есть практически для любых систем, так что можно еще поспорить, что считать настоящим стандартом.

Comment: @avp: Ну, на нестандартные расширения корпорации Зла линуксоиды ведь ругаются? :-) А стандартом нужно считать только стандарт, иначе закон джунглей: у кого большая часть рынка, тот и прав.

Comment: @VladD, конечно ругаются, особенно когда к ним пристают с вопросами типа "а почему у меня вот это не работает?".

По поводу джунглей, Вы тоже правы, у кого больше *активно пишущих* программеров, тот и прав.

Comment: @avp: You underestimate the power of the dark side. :-P http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=gcc&word2=visual+studio

Comment: @VladD, тем хуже для этой массы. Пусть мучаются.

Comment: 1. Проект создал правильно :)
2. Тогда для новичка смысла переходить на Visual Studio нет? Многопоточность и прочие умные штуки мне пока не нужны:)